# Avoiding dreaded use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string error when passing hashes as an argument

Tags: perl

I got something like this:

```
do_something({ key1 => 'value1', key2 => 'value2'});

sub do_something {
  $args = $_[0];
  print $$args{key1} . $$args{key2} . $$args{key3};
}
```

This throws the annoying `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string` error because I did not put a third key.

I'm lazy. So I don't want to add a third key to the hash. I'm OK with nothing getting printed for the third key in the function.

But I'm anal. I want to get rid of the error like so:

```
sub do_something {
  $args = $_[0];
  $third_key = $$args{key3} ? $$args{key3} : '';
  print $$args{key1} . $$args{key2} . $$args{key3};
}
```

However, I'm super ultra lazy. I don't want to have to write a line like that for every parameter that might be empty.

Is there a easy solution for this?

Comment: I would rather not do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
print join '', map $args->{$_}, keys %$args;
```

or

```
sub do_something {
  my %defaults = (
    key3 => ''
  );

  my $args = $_[0];
  # overlay defaults, this will modify the data structure in the caller
  $args->{$_} ||= $defaults{$_}
    foreach keys %defaults;

  print $args->{key1} . $args->{key2} . $args->{key3};
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the first solution there with the join. How does it know to set values to empty for keys it doesn't know exist?

The %defaults hash looks like pretty good solution. That's something I could throw into a init_arg() function to perhaps automate this.

Comment: It will print the keys that exist. If a key doesn't exist, it won't print it. If you have a key that exists but is undefined, you can throw a `grep defined` in there between the `map` and the `keys`.

Answer (score 3):

You have asked Perl to warn you about this when you wrote

```
use warnings;
```

So, you have some choices (from least to most safe):

1. Remove the `use warnings` so that no warnings are issued. The downside is that no warnings will be issued which will make debugging harder.
2. Remove the warning for uninitialized variables. This can be accomplished with: `no warnings qw(uninitialized);` Place this after you tell it to include warnings, and you will turn off just the one warning.
3. Remove the warning for uninitialized variables in the smallest possible scope. By placing the no warnings command within a smaller lexical scope, you can localize suppressing the warning to only places where you are expecting to print uninitialized variables to help you catch errors in other places.

This last option can be accomplished with the following code.

```
do_something({ key1 => 'value1', key2 => 'value2'});

sub do_something {
    no warnings qw(uninitialized);
    $args = $_[0];
    print $$args{key1} . $$args{key2} . $$args{key3};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have Perl 5.10 or better, use the logical defined-or operator (`//`) to allow for default defined values:

```
sub do_something {
  $args = $_[0];
  print $args->{key1} . $args->{key2} . ($args->{key3} // "");
}
```

Comment: Whoa. Didn't know that existed. Nice tip!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than passing a hash reference, just pass the hash values, and use the canonical Perl method for defaults for named arguments:

```
do_something(key1 => 'value1', key2 => 'value2');

sub do_something {
    my %args = (key1 => '',
                key2 => '',
                key3 => '',
                @_
               );

    print $args{key1} . $args{key2} . $args{key3};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I came up with, borrowing heavily from mwp's suggestion to use a default hash.

```
my $args = arg_init($_[0], {default1 => value1, defaults2 => value2}, 'value4', 'value5', 'value6');

sub arg_init {
  my $args = shift; # $args is a hashref of arguments
  set_default_args($args, shift) if ref($_[0]);
  while (my $arg = shift) {
    $$args{$arg} = exists $$args{$arg} ? $$args{$arg} : '';
  }
return $args;
}

sub set_default_args {
  my ($args, $defaults) = @_;
  $args->{$_} ||= $$defaults{$_}
    foreach keys %$defaults;
}
```

The arg_init function gets called to initialize arguments passed in a hash. First, it looks to see if default hash is a hash reference and, if it is, sets the default values provided in the hash reference. Next it looks at the scalar values passed to the function and sets those values to an empty string if they don't exists in the original hash argument.